# Get the diff between two html strings

Tags: java, diff

I would like to get the differences (string deleted and string added) between two HTML Strings. The function of the diff function has to give result as follows:

```
String html1 = "<h1>foo foo </h1>";
String html2 = "<h1>foo baar </h1>";

private String diff(String html1, String html2){
 ...
// diff method should return following:
return "<h1>foo <span class = "deleted">foo</span> <span class = "added">baar </span> </h1>";
}
```

I tried diff_match_patch but it has Problem with html tags. Example:

```
String html1 = "<ol><li>foo</li><li>baar</li></ol>" 
String html2 = "<ol><li>AA</li></ol>"

diff_match_patch(html1, html2) gives the following diff string:

<ol>
<li>AA<del style="background:#ffe6e6;"></li>
<li>BB</del>
</li>
</ol>
```

it should be:

```
<ol>
<li>AA</li>
<del style="background:#ffe6e6;"><li>BB</del>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You could try taking a look at [java-diff-utils](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/)

Comment: The answer should be, "replace <li>foo</li><li>baar</li> with <li>AA</li> at line 1 column 5".  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3452129/120163

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are telling they are Html strings ,For java they are  like any other normal `String`.

Try

```
    private String diff(String html1, String html2){

    // trim the string and null checks ..etc
    if(html1.equalsIgnoreCase(html2)){

     //  string  are same 
     }

    else {
      // they are different.
  }


    }
```